# How to create an article on a category blog without it being part of the blog

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

Basically I want to create a blog and an introduction to this blog. The introduction is an article, should show up on top and it's title should be the page's title.

The problem I am having is that so far the introductory article is shown as a blog post and treated as such, i.e. it's position changes when I publish a new post.

Could anyone let me know what I need to do? I am using joomla version 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to set a description to the category and along with css style it (e.g. position and layout) as you require.

It is likely that the option related to category description for the particular menu item is set to `Use Global`, which would probably be to hide it. So it is required to set this option to `Show`. The option can be found in the `category` tab of the menu item corresponding to this blog category.

Comment: That sounds as if it would work, however, it does not. Category description is on show but not showing up on the front end. Strangely, I don't have the same problem with the category title.
The following code shows up when I have category description set on show: `<div class="items-leading clearfix"><div class="leading-0">`
The category itself is published and the access is set to public.
I am using a custom made template, don't know whether that influences anything...

Comment: @Michael the markup you posted is related to the leading articles that are to be shown. If the value of the category description option of the menu item is `Show` then it is likely that it's a template thing. To make sure whether it is related to your template just switch templates and use one of the default ones shipped with joomla.

Comment: @Michael since it is related to the template then you will find a folder `html` under your template's folder, within that folder you will probably find another folder named `com_content` and then it will probably have `category/blog.php` or something like that. You will need to modify it and include the markup related to the description of the category. You can find the markup within the layout of another template as the one you already tried.

Comment: There was no override created in the Protostar template, it was just the default thing. Just to make sure, I created an override for both templates and checked the section you mentioned. It appears that both have the same code (see lines 36-45).
I never touched any of that code either, so it should be the same since the installation.

Comment: I seem to have found a solution, see my edited answer.